# Include both .f and .F90 file in Fortran main file header

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran77, intel-fortran

I am using some F77 fixed format code with my F90 program. I am trying to include both kinds of code in my main program. Here's how I have arranged my code:

Header files:

```
File Name:include.inc
include 'module_variables.F90'
include 'message.F90'
include 'module_common_functions.f90'
include 'module_input_gdf.F90'
...
```

Relavant LAPACK files

```
File Name: lapack.inc
include 'xerbla.f'
include 'strsm.f'
include 'slaswp.f'
include 'sgetrs.f'
include 'sgetrf.f'
...
```

Now my main program looks like:

```
include 'lapack.inc'
include 'include.inc'

program MDL_HydroD

   use module_variables
   use module_write_files
   use module_read_files
   ...
```

When I try to compile my main code with `ifort "MDL HydroD.F90"`, the F77 formatted files give error message:

```
xerbla.f(1): error #5078: Unrecognized token '\' skipped
*> \brief \b XERBLA
---^
```

This is because the compiler is reading the commented section (starts with *). Is there any way I can compile with both type of fortran code in my header.

Note: I am using Intel Composer XE 2013 with command prompt.

Comment: Why not make a module in separate file with the lapack subroutines? You do not have to include everything in one source file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are compiler specific directives (not part of the standard language), for that compiler, that allow you to change the source form in use.

Place the relevant directive before the include file, and then place the other directive after the include file to switch the source form back.  Perhaps:

```
!DEC$ NOFREEFORM
      INCLUDE 'lapack.inc'
!DEC$ FREEFORM
```

See http://software.intel.com/en-us/node/466230 for more information.

Comment: too bad they didn't put this in the standard