# How to write `make` file for separate source and build directory for large program with mixed Fortran F77 and F90 code

Tags: batch-file, fortran, fortran90, fortran77, intel-fortran

I have about 39 Fortran F90 source files and 35 Fortran 77 Lapack related files. I am using include statement in my main program to connect all these files.

I have created a batch file `make.bat` with command `ifort &quot;MDL HydroD.F90&quot;` which compiles my code and generates the `mdlhydrod.exe` file. In the process the Fortran compiler creates many `.mod` and `.obj` build files which makes it difficult to manage. I would like to put my source files under a directory `Source` and lapack library files in a directory `lapack` and build files in a directory `Debug`.

Could anyone help me modify my `make.bat` file so that `ifort` looks at `Source` directory and build in `Debug` directory.

Thank you for help.

Currently using `make.bat` has only one line of command:

```
File Name: make.bat

ifort  &quot;MDL HydroD.F90&quot;
```

Working on a make file to be used with `nmake` (incomplete):

```
File Name: make.mak:

#Make File for MDL HydroD
# Compiler options
FC          :=  ifort
VPATH       :=  src
BINDIR      :=  bin

$(BINDIR):
    mkdir -p $(BINDIR)

clean:
@rm -rf $(BINDIR)
```

Comment: Are you actually using a make tool in this process or is your script just called make.bat?

Comment: It's just my file `make.bat`. Compile time is not too high, so though a simple batch file should be enough.

Comment: I am also trying to write a simple `makefile.mak` which can be used with the `nmake` command line tool. But I am very new to this and couldn't find any good tutorial for Windows OS yet. It would be helpful if you can direct me towards the right path.

Comment: How do you want a help if you do not show the script?

Comment: Showing the script might be a good start (especially if it involves more than just that simple `ifort` command). If the question is how to tell `ifort` where to find sources and libraries then that sounds like something the `ifort` documentation or help output should be able to tell you.

Comment: Edited my question with my `make.bat` and `make.mak` file. My apologies for not posting them earlier. I don't know how to write `make` scripts and trying to get it together from snippets from different web pages. Thank you for your help.

Comment: you ought to edit the question (title) to reflect you are asking for help with make. Question really  has nothing to do with specifically with intel fortran.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using a strange way of working with source files, which you showed in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22752730/include-both-f-and-f90-file-in-fortran-main-file-header), it will be very difficult to change this.

For recapitulation, you include everything in a single source file using the `include` statement. This looks pretty unfortunate to me and I commented on that there. If you have one source file, you are forced to build it with one command, there is no place for any fine control. This is not the issue of a bash or bat script vs. Makefile.

You can probably still keep some files `included` in some groups that are logically similar, if you need no finer control on that, but I see not much reason for that.

Remove the includes or at least the relevant ones. Then you can just do

```
ifort Source/the_source_file1 -c Output/name_of_obj1 -module the_directory_for_modules -I the_directory_for_modules  -other_flags
```

for every file.  And then in the end:

```
ifort Output/name_of_obj1 Output/name_of_obj2 Output/name_of_obj3 .... -o the_result
```

In Scons (which I would use) it would be like this (tested on couple of dummy files). The file `Sconstruct`:

```
import os

env = Environment(tools=['default','ifort'])

env.Append(ENV = {'PATH' : os.environ['PATH']})
try:
  env.Append(ENV = {'LIBRARY_PATH' : os.environ['LIBRARY_PATH']})
except:
  pass

env.Append(F90FLAGS='-g -fast') #whatever flags you need
env.Append(FORTRANFLAGS='-g -fast') #whatever flags you need

outdir = "Output/"

srcdir = "Sources/"

lapackdir = "lapack/"


objs = []
for file in os.listdir(srcdir):
  objs += env.Object(target=outdir+os.path.splitext(file)[0], source=srcdir+file)

for file in os.listdir(lapackdir):
  objs += env.Object(target=outdir+os.path.splitext(file)[0], source=lapackdir+file)

env.Append(FORTRANMODDIR = outdir)

objs = filter(lambda o: str(o)[-4:] != '.mod', objs)

prg = env.Program(target="bin/result.exe", source= objs)

Default(prg)
```

Comment: Thank you @vladimir-f for your response in both my posts. From your response, I understand I should write `ifort` command for each Fortran code in appropriate order to create the `Object` files and then link them to create `.exe` file. I was wondering if a make file such as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004702/how-can-i-create-a-makefile-for-c-projects-with-src-obj-and-bin-subdirectories) can be made which will automatically search for all source files inside `src`  directory, or its not possible since there is an order of dependence between the codes?

Comment: With Fortran modules, you have to care for he correct order and dependency. This is not something `make` is good at doing automatically. I no longer personally use `make` for Fortran, because  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scons is so much better.

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to SCons. I will learn and implement it in my code later. For immediate purpose I think your idea of multiple `ifort` command written in a batch file will work.