# Directives in Included files in Fortran

Tags: fortran, include, intel-fortran

Suppose I have a file `test.f90` (free-form code) that includes some other file `foo.h` (fixed code).

The two didn't work well together because they have different comment styles, so I put a preprocessor directive `!DIR$ NOFREEFORM` at the top of the `foo.h` source code, which tells Intel's Fortran Compiler `ifort` to interpret that file as fixed-form source code.

Unfortunately, the rest of my code in `test.f90` gets errors that indicate `ifort` is interpreting it as fixed-form rather than free-form code.

I haven't rigorously checked, but **is it possible that the preprocessor directive in `foo.h` is causing `ifort` to interpret the code in `test.f90` as fixed-form?** I didn't think this was possible because `ifort` treats each included file as a separate compilation, rather than just copy-pasting the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22752730/include-both-f-and-f90-file-in-fortran-main-file-header/22753383.  I see that this was pointed out to you in a comment to an earlier variant of your question - you indeed *haven't rigorously checked*, you haven't even followed advice already provided.

Comment: !DIR$ NOFREEFORM is not a "preprocessor directive", it is a compiler directive, The documentation says, "When the FREEFORM or NOFREEFORM directives are used, they remain in effect for the remainder of the program unit, or until the opposite directive is used. " So you need the corresponding FREEFORM directive at the end. Or, where you INCLUDE it, bracket the INCLUDE with those directives (the better approach in my view.)

Comment: Downvote from me. Please at least *pretend* to put some effort into your question beforehand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest standard states

> The effect of the INCLUDE line is as if the referenced source text
>   physically replaced the INCLUDE line prior to program processing.

so it is entirely possible, in fact absolutely inevitable, that the preprocessor directive in the included file causes the compiler to change its interpretation of the code.

`include`-d files are **not** separate compilation units.

I guess you should be able to use`!DEC$ FREEFORM` to switch the compiler's behaviour back again.